# Angular & CSS: How to change the horizontal Navigation bar to Vertical on button click

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to change my horizontal navigation bar to vertical on button click using angularJs... 
I tried to apply ng-style and ng-click but could not achieve want i wanted... this is my code..so far

```
<li> <a href="#"><button **ng-click="change={trasform:'rotate(90deg)'}"**>change</button>
</a></li> 

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-default navbar-light bg-navigation" role="navigation" **ng-style="change"** style="margin-top:7px;border: solid;border-width: 3px; border-color:blue; color: indigo">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>

<li>  <a href='#'>  <button id="changeVertical">change</button>
</a>
</li>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-default navbar-light bg-navigation" role="navigation" id="Navbar"   >
</nav>
</body>
<script>
$("#changeVertical").click(function(){
   $("nav").css("transform", "rotate(90deg)");
});
</script>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>

<li>  <a href='#'>  <button id="changeVertical">change</button>
</a>
</li>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-default navbar-light bg-navigation" role="navigation" id="Navbar"   >
</nav>
</body>
<script>
$("#changeVertical").click(function(){
   $("nav").css("transform", "rotate(90deg)");
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I think we should not mix `jquery` with angularjs :)

Comment: can we just not achieve by angularjs And CSS??

Comment: Without angular ,you can use jquery and achieve it.But without css codes,I doubt it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via `css` by conditional `ng-class`, just make some boolean flag `true\false` on button click to apply class dynamically.

Example demo:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.rotateNow = false;
});
```

```css
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Opera */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#nav {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .5em;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  transition: .3s all;
  /* rotate gradually instead of instantly */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <br>
  <button ng-click="rotateNow=!rotateNow">Click To Rotate</button>
  <hr>
  <nav id="nav" ng-class="{'rotate':rotateNow}">
    This will rotate
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks .. but by doing so it will fulfill the functionality of rotating the navbar from horizontal tovertical but how will the contents get shifted?? @anoop

Comment: <nav id="nav" ng-class="{'rotate':rotateNow}">
        <a class="rotate  " href="#">Home </a>
        <a class="rotate  " href="#">Home </a>
        <a class="rotate  " href="#">Home </a>
        <a class="rotate  " href="#">Home </a>

    </nav>

Comment: To align the content by css, will make view more complex and probably will break the responsive nature too, So  I would suggest to create `2 separate navigation bar(horizontall and verical)` and then show\hide with some condition.(something like  : `ng-if="showVerical"`)